# Cannot open "Display" settings, error "Could not get screen information"

Tags: display, 15.10

**Display** in Settings menu shows

> Could not get screen information

And **Change Desktop Background** on Right-Click menu just opens Settings.

Is it bug in update, or did I do something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue which I solved through re-installing the Ubuntu desktop by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens, reinstalling the Ubuntu Desktop has fixed the issue for me. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The above solution was not working (tried it under 16.04 LTS)
But thanks to
http://pifuge.com/ubuntu/fjvU-ubuntu-could-not-get-screen-information-after-upgrade
From a terminal window, I did

```
ps x|grep control-center
```

found gnome control-center process running, killed it using the good old kill -9
and launch `unity-control-center` instead

All display information are there

Comment: Could you tell, how you killed it?

Comment: just a kill -9 followed by the process id returned by the previous command. I don't know your level of knownledge on Unix. I you want I can add some screen captures

Comment: yeah, thats what I tried, but it said no such process id... hmm, anyway I don't have a `unity-control-center`

Comment: Why not giving it a try with  
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install unity-control-center` ?

Comment: unity-control-center has only few settings. I do not see anything with Display setttings