# External monitor(s) dark out on one account and I cannot set monitor layout, how to fix?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, xrandr, gpu-driver

Seemingly "out of nowhere", my Dell e7440 running Ubuntu 16.04 with 2 external monitors displays only the login screen for external monitors, when I login it shows system error and external monitors will dark out.

Couldn't see the display options as well:

`could not get screen information`

**PS: Everything works in guest session**

What could be wrong with my setup?

---

This didn't help:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

(From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698428/cannot-open-display-settings-error-could-not-get-screen-information))

Output of `xrandr`, as requested in a comment:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6400 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-2 connected 2560x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1200x960      59.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: A wild guess, but since it works in another account: possibly you `monitors.xml` file got messed up. This doesnt explain the login screen though. To find out: rename `~/.config/monitors.xml`, immediately log out and back in. If it didn't help, simply restore the renamed file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks! That fixed that fixed the monitors not working, but I still can't change the monitor options, eq location, currently it's as if they were all side by side.

Comment: I have to run, but could you post the output of `xrandr`? Also, another wild guess, but would a restart chnage anything?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, xrandr output pasted, restart didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Could you describe how you'd like the screens arranged? Possible because of a bu, changing in in monitors (gui) doesn't work, but from cli we might work around.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you form helping me so far! I'd like it to be so that 24'' is on the top left, 27'' is top right (these 2 bottoms aligned) and laptop in the bottom and center, hopefully I expressed myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Corrupted monitors.xml file

As mentioned in a comment, if your monitors darken on (only) one account, working on other(s), most likely your monitors.xml file is somehow corrupted. To fix, remove `~/.config/monitors.xml`, immediately log out and back in.

#### Setting up your (complicated) monitor setup from cli

You mentioned the step above fixed the darkening screen(s), but you still cannot setup the screens in the layout you wanted (see below). That is possibly caused by a bug. We might very well be able to work around it by setting it up from cli.

To set up the screen layout as you described in a comment:

[image]

You'd need to run the `xrandr` command:

```bsh
xrandr --output DP1-1 --pos 0x0 \
--output DP1-2 --pos 1920x0 \
--output DP1-1 --pos 0x360 \
--output eDP1 --pos 1440x1440
```

...if I made no typo or other mistake...

#### Explanation

*Normally*, in a complicated screen layout, you simply need to work from left to right, from top to bottom.

**However**
If you don't know for sure what is the current layout, you cannot place the *first* screen, other than `0x0`. If there is empty space in the top of your screen layout, `xrandr` will remove the empty space and change e.g. `0x200` into `0x0`. Therefore the steps need to be:

1. position `DP1-1` and `DP1-2` horizontally *top-alligned*:

   ```
   xrandr --output DP1-1 --pos 0x0 --output DP1-2 --pos 1920x0
   ```

   [image]
2. only *then* bottom-align `DP1-1` with `DP1-2`:

   ```
   xrandr --output DP1-1 --pos 0x360
   ```

   [image]
3. place `eDP1` in the middle below the other two screens:

   ```
   xrandr --output eDP1 --pos 1440x1280
   ```

   [image]

#### How to use

1. Copy the small script below into an empty file, save it as `setup_screens.sh`

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   xrandr --output DP1-1 --pos 0x0 \
   --output DP1-2 --pos 1920x0 \
   --output DP1-1 --pos 0x360 \
   --output eDP1 --pos 1440x1440
   ```
2. Make it executable
3. Test-run it from a terminal, run the command:

   ```
   /path/to/setup_screens.sh
   ```
4. Either run it from a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   /path/to/setup_screens.sh
   ```

   or run it on login:  Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /path/to/setup_screens.sh"
   ```

Comment: Hi @SilverRingvee, did you notice the answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you for being so helpful and creating such a thorough answer. I will try it on Thursday because I am off for the conference. Thank you again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So I finally had a chance to test it! It indeed changed the positioning of the monitors and mouse seems to move as it should, although the windows are a pit off, especially when I put them fullscreen - the are not full screen at all, and a bit out of screen as well. See the screenshot: http://imgur.com/Fb1imbi And of course, thank you so much for helping me so far!

Comment: @SilverRingvee I made a mistake (y- wise of the third screen) does that change it?

Comment: Hey, Sorry can you specify the mistake, I don't really get it. There was also a typo "ouput" in the second line. Thanks

Comment: Hi @SilverRingvee the vertical positioning of screen `eDP1` was incorrect (too high) fixed now. Indeed also the typo you mention. I wrote the answer while I was quickly getting a high fever, might have helped in a bad way :( Does it work now?

Comment: Helped! I wish there were more people like you out there! Thank you so much for your help! Do you also know if this is something that will be fixed in an update?

Comment: Don't mention it, the fact that it works is the satisfaction :). If it will be fixed depends on the cooperation of the manufacturers of the videocard(s) I am afraid...